# Using QTcpSocket for continuous fast usage

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, qtcpsocket

I need to implement a client that reads data at 300 Hz (300 samples per second). When working with C sockets, everything was ok accept for the fact that I need to run a continuous while loop to get the data from the server (which blocks the client from handling anything else).
So, I've decided trying to move to QTcpsocket, in order to handle signals that are coming from other object to the client object. But when I connect the Qtcpsocket, and connect the signal for reading

```
connect(socket,&QTcpSocket::readyRead, this, &client::handleReadyRead, Qt::ConnectionType::QueuedConnection);
```

this is my handler -

```
QByteArray b = socket->read(12);
int packetLength = (unsigned char)b[6] << CHAR_BIT;
packetLength |=  (unsigned char)b[7];
b = socket->read(packetLength);
```

(I get a 12 byte long header for each packet)
Now I get a very slow client - It handles about maybe 3 samples per second...I've checked to see how much `bytesavailable()` returns, and it looks like data is piling up in the sockets buffer.
What am I doing wrong? I have to get a very fast client, but I'm not sure that the way I'm reading is optimal. 
Is there a more efficient way to do it?

Thank you

Comment: Profile your application and see where the bottleneck is.

Comment: I'm actually using a mini-project to test it so its pretty much just the client running. Profiling shows that the event loop takes a lot of the time, but can it be avoided?

Comment: You are calling `socket->read(packetLength)` without knowing whether or not `packetLength` bytes are available.  If they aren't then the next read will be out of sync with the data stream.

Comment: Even if I check this using `if (socket->bytesAvailable() >= packetLength){ b = socket->read(packetLength); }` it changes nothing

Comment: When you say "the event loop takes a lot of time" can you tell us the specific function name?

Comment: you can look at the profiling results for 30 seconds of reading here- http://imgur.com/a/8kjUV

Comment: When you say "the event loop takes a lot of time" you realize that your read handler *is* part of the event loop?  To diagnose the problem any further you'll need to show more of your `handleReadyRead` implementation.

Comment: Note also that checking for `socket->bytesAvailable() >= packetLength` before reading isn't sufficient.  If the test fails then the next `handleReadyRead` invocation will probably interpret the packet body as a new header.

Comment: This is all of the handler-  `QByteArray b = socket->read(12);
    int packetLength = (unsigned char)b[6] << CHAR_BIT;
    packetLength |=  (unsigned char)b[7];
    if (socket->bytesAvailable() >= packetLength){
        b = socket->read(packetLength);
    }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current `handleReadyRead` assumes that a complete packet is available to read and that packet boundaries are preserved.  TCP doesn't work that way -- it's just a byte stream.

A better approach might be to accumulate data into a `QByteArray` and read packets from that `QByteArray` as and when they become available.

So, assuming your `client` class has a data member...

```
QByteArray m_data;
```

I would expect the logic to be something like...

```
void handleReadyRead ()
{

  /*
   * Append all available data to m_data.
   */
  m_data.append(socket->readAll());

  /*
   * Now work our way through m_data processing complete
   * packets as we find them.  At any given point offset
   * is the total size of all complete packets (including
   * headers) processed thus far.
   */
  int offset = 0;
  while (m_data.length() >= offset + 12) {

    /*
     * We have enough data for a header so read the packet length.
     */
    int packetLength  = (unsigned char)m_data[offset + 6] << CHAR_BIT;
    packetLength     |= (unsigned char)m_data[offset + 7];

    /*
     * Check to see if we have sufficient data for the packet
     * body.  If not then we're done for the time being.
     */
    if (m_data.length() < offset + 12 + packetLength)
      break;

    /*
     * There is enough data for the complete packet so read it.
     * Note that the following will include the header data in the
     * packet variable.  If that's not desired then change it to...
     *
     *   auto packet = m_data.mid(offset + 12, packetLength);
     */
    auto packet = m_data.mid(offset, 12 + packetLength);

    /*
     * Do whatever you want with the packet.
     */
    do_something_with_the_packet(packet);

    /*
     * Update the offset according to the amount of data read.
     */
    offset += 12 + packetLength;
  }

  /*
   * Finally, remove the data processed from the beginning of
   * the QByteArray.
   */
  if (offset)
    m_data = m_data.right(data.size() - offset);
}
```

The above is untested but is certainly along the lines of code I've used in the past.

Comment: This really works, thank you. Now I just have find out why I'm getting the packets in a wrong order....